# img tag not working in drupal content

Tags: html, drupal

I tried to use `<img src="sites/all/themes/bluez/images/team/zin.png">` in drupal content. But, it doesn't working properly. I also choose Full HTML in text format. 
The image only show blank screen and when I click the image url, it says 
**Not Found
The requested URL "/planz/node/sites/all/themes/bluez/images/team/zin.png" was not found on this server.**
Please help my problem. I'm new to Drupal. 
Thanks.

Comment: What is the correct absolute URL? (The full address including the domain name)

Comment: I'm running on localhost.

Comment: OK, but what is the correct URL to the image? What directory is it in?

Comment: The image is located in localhost/planz/sites/all/themes/bluez/images/team/zin.png
I added the image file in the themes folder called "BlueZ"

Comment: This is my html.
<h2>Zin Ko Oo</h2>
<p>
<img src="/sites/all/themes/bluez/images/team/zin.png" alt="Zin Ko Oo" width="114" height="137">
</p>

Comment: It'd have to be `/planz/sites/all/themes/bluez/images/team/zin.png`

Answer (score 0):

Try to make the target path absolute. 
Visit the absolute path from your browser - There you can easily see if you have the correct path or not! When you have the correct path, than you can insert that to your code!